# How find consecutive results in mongoose

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

imagine I have the next collection:

**Files**

| _id | code |
| --- | --- |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#1 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#2 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#3 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#10 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#12 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#12-1 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-1 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2 |
| randomid | ZA/1/1/1-1#120 |

And I'm trying to get the "Childs" using:

```
Model.find({ code: { $regex: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12'} })
```

And what I want:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-1"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-1"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2"
    "__v": 0
  },

]
```

But Im getting (same but including the #120):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-1"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-1"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2"
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "randomid",
    "code": "ZA/1/1/1-1#120"
    "__v": 0
  },

]
```

So, that's why I'm looking for help, how do I prevent this from happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

You want to get the children/consecutive items which might be defined with this code format:

- `ZA/1/1/1-1#12`
- `ZA/1/1/1-1#12-SOMETHING`

Which translates to `ZA/1/1/1-1#12(\-.+)?$`, or [`/ZA\/1\/1\/1\-1#12(\-.+)?$/`](https://regexr.com/76m4e).

These results match what you wanted

```
test> db.sth.find().pretty()
[
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12-1' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#120' }
]

test> db.sth.find({ code: { $regex: "ZA/1/1/1-1#12(\-.+)?$"} }).pretty()
[
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12-1' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2' }
]

test> db.sth.find({ code: { $regex: /ZA\/1\/1\/1\-1#12(\-.+)?$/} }).pretty()
[
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12-1' },
  { _id: 'randomid', code: 'ZA/1/1/1-1#12-2-2' }
]
```